# How to add SQL Server 2008 admin

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, azure, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

Ok I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am connected to SQL Azure via SQL Server 2008.

Later on, created a database called `MyDatabase` and added a few tables in it.

So, I am trying to add another user who will have admin roles (update, drop...)

I created user Michael:

```
CREATE LOGIN Michael 
WITH PASSWORD = 'Some password';
```

and then:

```
CREATE USER Michael FOR LOGIN Michael;
GO
```

Now, I can connect to database server with `Michael` credentials and see the database, but I don't see any tables in it.

Tnx in advanced! :)

**EDIT:**
When i connect to SQL Azure Management it says the following:

```
The current user does not have VIEW DATABASE STATE permissions on this database.
```

Comment: [sp_addrolemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) Though I'm not clear if you're doing this on a Sql 2008 Azure instance, or what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 to connect to a SQL Azure Database Server.

Comment: Great. [Here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336235.aspx). Do you know the roles on the server and what permissions they have?

Comment: Tnx, i have completely forgotten that i am working with azure, not casual sql server :) i will try this

Comment: The same problem occurs again :/ I created it, connect it, and under MyDatabase i can't see any table

Comment: Did you assign the login a role? Does the role have permissions to that DB and all of its objects?

Comment: i edit the first post :)

Comment: `GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO Michael`

Comment: when i try this in master it says that the grantor is not allowed. But, when i added it to MyDatabase it works. Next, i am able to connect to SQL Azure Management but again, i could not see the Tables.

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/sql-azure-management/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Managing Databases and Logins in SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336235.aspx)

or

TL:DR version:

```
-- first, connect to the master database:
CREATE LOGIN login1 WITH password='<ProvidePassword>';

-- Then Establish a new connection to your database and execute this:
CREATE USER login1User FROM LOGIN login1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here`s another way when you can't even connect to the server.  When SQL Server was installed, by a Domain account, you user was not added.  You have to start the server from the command line and add the user (which is most probably you).

This [great blog post](http://blogs.ameriteach.com/chris-randall/2009/12/11/sql-server-2008-forgot-to-add-an-administrator-account.html?printerFriendly=true) saved me